# How to ensure a particular order of execution of data sets in SSRS 2008R2

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have report with several data sets.

DS1 - Executes an SP which Truncates and loads a Table based on the year and period passed as a parameter by user from the report.

DS2 and DS3 - Select from the table loaded in last step.

Is there any way to ensure that DS1 executes before DS2 and DS3? I know that there is a data source property which tells SSRS to run the Data Sets in a single transaction and hence execute them sequentially rather than in parallel as explained in this link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2008/08/07/dataset-execution-order.aspx

But my doubt is that when I deploy this report to a report server,I am going to use a shared data source already created there. What will happen to this property which I set at design time after deployment?

Comment: Ick. Consider using a view, or table valued function, instead.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?